# Copy null values from one table to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

How can I find all null values from respective columns of a table_A and then copy or insert those null values to respective columns of another table_B which has an exact schema (i.e. all columns) like table_A.

Is there any way we can do it dynamically or without specifying any column names of the table. Other approaches are also welcomed.

I have tried the following to find columns having `null` values:

```
select * 
from table_A
where col_1 is null or col_2 is null
```

Comment: I don't understand. If a row has these values: col1 = NULL, col2 = NULL, col3 = 333. You want to copy the null values to the other table. The other table has the same columns, so you create a row with col1 = NULL, col2 = NULL. And for col3? Which value would you want to insert into that row? NULL as well? Then you'd only insert empty rows. Please elaborate.

Comment: Do `table_A` and `table_B` contain the exact same rows (meaning the same Primary Key IDs), or is there a difference in the IDs and/or the number of rows? Please **[edit]** the question to make it more complete.

Comment: Give a concrete example of what you want to do, actual example data for the two tables and the results you should get  when using those two example tables.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you want to do it dynamically, without having to specify column names, you need code that writes SQL (that's what Dynamic-SQL is).  The SQL-writing-code reads the schema of the database and writes one or more sql statement to do what you want, but *that* SQL statement has the column names in it (SQL cant do *anything* without column names).  So, work out how to do it with column names first, then work out what code you need to dynamically generate that SQL.

Answer (score 0):

## Finding the fields of a table

This is how you can select column names of a table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_A' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourSchemaName';
```

This is nice, but you also want to loop over the column names.

## Creating a cursor for your results

```
DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR select_statement
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_A' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourSchemaName';
```

## Open your cursor

```
OPEN column_cursor;
```

## Loop your cursor

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO 
            @column_name;
    END;
```

Note that `column_name` is a variable you need to declare earlier.

## Build your where clause

At each step of your loop on your cursor, you will need to add some new criteria. Your final criteria will be like

**c1 is null or c2 is null or ... or cn is null**

So, you need to initialize your `@where` variable to null and have this logic in your cursor loop:

```
IF ISNULL(@where)
BEGIN
    @where = CONCAT(' ', @column_name, ' IS NULL ');
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    @where = CONCAT(@where, ' OR ', @column_name, ' IS NULL ');
END
```

## Build your update

Now you have a nice where clause, but let's generate the set clause of your update as well, let's assume that you have a @set variable initialized to null. This is what you need inside the loop:

```
IF ISNULL(@set)
BEGIN
    @set = CONCAT(' ', @column_name, ' = CASE WHEN source.', @column_name, ' IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE target.', @column_name, ' END ');
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    @set = CONCAT(@set, ', ', @column_name, ' = CASE WHEN source.', @column_name, ' IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE target.', @column_name, ' END ');
END
```

## Let's build an update query

```
@query = CONCAT('UPDATE target SET ', @set, ' FROM ', @source_table, ' source JOIN ', @target_table, ' target ON source.id = target.id WHERE ', @where, ';');
```

## Execute a String as query

```
EXEC (@query);
```